# how to get driving distance between two locations in nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-maps

I have two points on Google Map and I need to calculate the driving distance by node js
I tries to use node-geometry-library but I think I didn't know how to use it
and after some research I found that I can use google map API but I don't know to use it in nodejs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try Google-Distance-Matrix

The information returned is based on the recommended route between start and end points, as calculated by the Google Maps API

https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-distance-matrix

Comment: thanks for your response this package solved my problem

Comment: I would recommend https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js instead.

Comment: @jpoehnelt thanks for your recommend I will try it